# Change the height and source of an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iFrame on my page and a list of links underneath.
I need the links to change the source and height of the iFrame and also go to the top of the page, to a named anchor "top", when clicked.

Possibly using jQuery?

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes jQuery. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I have only loaded the the iframe

  <div class="profile_container">
    <iframe src="profiles/user01.html" width="900" height="440" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="figher_profile"></iframe>
  </div>

Comment: how about posting some code, since you're obviously asking for an example :)

Comment: I'm just not sure how to set up the jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep it is definitely possible to do so using jquery. I do not know exactly what the code inside your iframe looks like, but to select an iframe by its name, for example, you would do:

```
$("iframe[name='figher_profile']").contents();
```

Then to set its height

```
$("iframe[name='figher_profile']").height($("iframe[name='figher_profile']").contents().find("html").css("height", "100")); //Setting the height to 100 px
```

To change the source of an iframe:

```
var location = "http://google.com";
$("iframe[name='figher_profile']").attr('src', location);
```

If you want to do the same with an iframe with an id or class just replace [name='ifr'] with #id  or .class like below:

```
$("iframe#id") //for id
$("iframe.class") //for class
```

Comment: Also for the back to top link, please see: http://agyuku.net/2009/05/back-to-top-link-using-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of ways you can do this... as such ill just post the most remedial way..

```
<div class="profile_container">
</div>
<a href="#" id="link1">abcd</a>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var srcLink = 'http://placehold.it/440x440';
  var srcheight = '440'; 
  var iframeHtml = '<iframe src="'+srcLink+'" width="900" height="'+srcheight+'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="figher_profile"></iframe>';
  $('#link1').click(function(){
    $('.profile_container').html(iframeHtml);
  });
});
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gorelative/AmKJX/1/

Comment: @clockwork189's method is much cleaner, as he isn't removing the DOM node and reinserting it like i am.